# Changing the height/width when calling another graph as an in-page popup using PXPopupRedirectException

Tags: acumatica

We added a button via a graph extension to the sales order page. When we click this new button (based on selected detail row) we call a PXPopupRedirectException calling another graph to represent the popup panel. The problem we have is the default size is very small. We would like to have the width of the popup panel/graph be 100% of the parent page if possible.

The call in our button uses this...

```
throw new PXPopupRedirectException(graph, string.Empty, true);
```

From the screen shot below you can see how small the panel opens. What can we do by default to get the panel to auto fit the full size of the parent area as outlined in the red box? If we open the graph as a standard new tab/page then it looks fine.

[image: Screen shot of my issue with panel size]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the current default fix:  You can set the size of a popup window in the code-behind of the screen using your graph:

```cs
public partial class Page_CR301000 : PX.Web.UI.PXPage
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.PopupHeight = 700;
        Master.PopupWidth = 900;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the sizes can't be set as percentages of the parent screen width using this method.

Could you please describe your scenario and detail requirements?  We might be able to give our popups a little more flexiblility.  Thanks!

Comment: Our graph is used on other pages and even by itself. It needs to have a pure connection to the parent (in this example the sales order page). When we had the pop up be a new window it would not update the sales order correctly as it treated it as two seperate pages opened and the users would get very confused. Locking the pop up graph into the parent (sales order) page works much better. However the default size is very small. Does this help Katherine?

Comment: While i have yet to test this... I wonder if you set the size to a large number, I assume the page will auto adjust the size to not be larger than the frame the panel exists within?

Comment: I have tested this and it at least an improvement. It would be nice to have the ability to default the full open space of the pop up area for quick entry by the user (no need to resize - which if you do resize there is an issue with the panel ghosting). Thanks for the feedback Katheriine

Comment: Anybody know how to get modifications to the codebehind file into the customization project?